# Angular Universal set set-cookies in request header

Tags: angular, cookies, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, setcookie

I have anngular Universal SSR application with authentication. I save auth token inside http cookies(set-cookies). Now when I refresh application I see unauthenticated page at first, and after a second it converts to authenticated state.

I understand that this happens because Universals renderer server doesn't pass token from cookies to API when rendering page. So how can I force Universal server to render page in authenticated state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular universal does not transfer cookies when using `HttpClient` ([github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15730)). You can add them manually, using an interceptor.

**interceptor.ts**

```
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

@Injectable()
export class CookieInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private httpRequest) 
  {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (this.httpRequest) //If optional request is provided, we are server side
    {
      req = req.clone(
      { 
        setHeaders: 
        {
            Cookie: this.httpRequest.headers.cookie
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

You might get the following error

> Refused to set unsafe header 'Cookie'

A possible workaround, suggested in this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15730#issuecomment-330461230), is to bypass xhr2's default security behaviour for unsafe headers

For angular 7 (and I guess 8), the following works

**server.ts**

```
import * as xhr2 from 'xhr2';
xhr2.prototype._restrictedHeaders = {};
```

I haven't tested for angular 9, but I think you need a [different workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15730#issuecomment-572992686) for the unsafe cookie header

```
// activate cookie for server-side rendering
export class ServerXhr implements XhrFactory {
  build(): XMLHttpRequest {
    xhr2.prototype._restrictedHeaders.cookie = false;
    return new xhr2.XMLHttpRequest();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: XhrFactory, useClass: ServerXhr }],
  ...
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did yesterday. So far the best answer in internet.

Comment: could you add the imports for the code as well? where does `xhr2` come from?

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It helped me find a solution to my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647880/2112936 I tried using sessions for auth at first but it didn't work with Angular SSR so I went with the cookie approach instead.

Comment: HERO! haha, really, being struggling with this for ages!!

Comment: request alway null

Comment: i knew there had to be a solution like this, how come i only find this after trying every other posted solution!

Comment: how can we apply this to angular-ssr? is there an equivalent to "REQUEST" there? I can deduce the if(isServer) by using plaftomId but I don't have a way to get the cookies from the request